# Why won't my wordle clone set the right answer green in code.org?

Tags: javascript, code.org

So I am using the code.org wordle dataset to recreate a wordle clone. The problem is, all the code works fine yet when you input the right answer, it comes out as red (supposed to be green). If someone could take a look at my code and see what is wrong that would be greatly appreciated.

```
//Getting Wordle Answer 
var answers = getColumn("Wordle", "validWordleAnswer");
var index = (randomNumber(0, answers.length));
console.log(answers[index]);
var letters =  ["letter1", "letter2", "letter3", "letter4", "letter5"];


//Checking Words
onEvent("wordbutton", "click", function( ) {
  var guess = getProperty("wordInput", "text");
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (guess == answers) {
      setProperty(letters[i], "background-color", "green");
    } else  {
      setProperty(letters[i], "background-color", "red");
    }
    setProperty(letters[i], "text", guess[i]);
    setProperty("wordsUsedOuput", "text", guess[i]);
  }
});
```

Specifically line 5 and 6, confused as to what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect `getColumn` to assign an array with multiple results to `answers`.

Your `wordbutton` event is comparing that array to `guess`, which is a string.  So, the line `if (guess == answers) {` is likely a bug.  Perhaps you meant, `if (guess == answers[index]) {`?

Also, you're coloring the whole word red or green based on the answer.  If your intent is to check a letter at a time, your code might look a little more like:

```
let answer=answers[index];
if (guess.charAt(i) == answer.charAt(i)) {
    ...
}
```